# Unable to access a directory despite belonging to a group with write permission

Tags: files, permissions, group

I am learning basic file permission in Linux and tried actions below.
I have a folder "music" to which group "music" has wxr permission.
I have user "finxxi" added into group "music".

When user "finxxi" tries to create files in folder "music", "Permission denied" is reached. Since user "finxxi" belongs to group "music" which should has wxr permission, why permission denied?

```
    finxxi@MyST ~ $ ls -la music
    total 8
    drwxrwxr-x  2 root   music  4096 Dec  2 06:47 .
    drwxr-xr-x 25 finxxi finxxi 4096 Dec  2 06:47 ..
    finxxi@MyST ~ $ members music
    finxxi
    finxxi@MyST ~ $ cd music
    finxxi@MyST ~/music $ > test.txt
    bash: test.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you log out and back in after adding `finxxi` to the `music` group?  If not, try it...

Comment: thanks @garethTheRed ! it seems users do need to logout and in to refresh the granted permission. good to know.

Comment: You could also do `newgrp music` to log in to the new group, but that just spawns the new shell process, the old one is still intact.  On the other hand, it's quicker.